# How to remove the ESC characters from Notepad++

Tags: escape-characters, notes

How to remove the ESC characters in black background from Notepad++ v6.7.3

[image: H]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about a Windows application

Answer (score 8):

What should be removed is not simply the ASCII escape character, but the entire escape sequence, which terminates the the "m".

In *Notepad++*, you can substitute regular expressions.  Using an answer by @progm as a starting point, this expression will search for escape sequences for *colors*:

```
\x1b\[[0-9;]*m
```

Tick off **`Search Mode = Regular expression`**, and click **`Find Next`**.

Further reading:

- [Notepad++, How to remove all non ascii characters with regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20889996/notepad-how-to-remove-all-non-ascii-characters-with-regex)

Comment: I additionally needed to search for `\033\(B` (the "font reset" command for color codes)

Comment: Magical, thank you

Answer (score 0):

To delete the ASCII ESC character use:

```
tr -d '\033' <infile >outfile
```